# Axios post request of form data send nothing

Tags: reactjs, axios

I need to send form data to my database with an Axios post request, but nothing is sent.
The data I need is what is in movieId input.

Maybe the formData.append is not well written ?

````
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    
    const onSubmit = data => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('movieId', data.movieId);

        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/addMovie", formData)

        .then(response => {
            console.log("Status: ", response.status);
            console.log("Data: ", response.data);
          }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Something went wrong!', error);
          });

    }
    return (
        <div id="ModalBackground">
            <div id="ModalContainer">
                <button id= "closeModal" onClick= {() => {closeModal(false)}}>X</button>
                <h1 id= "formTitle">Numéro du film</h1>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} id="addMovieForm">
                    <input type="text" id="movieId" {...register("movieId")} required></input>
                    <input id= "submit" type="submit" value="Ajouter !"></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


    );
}


export default Modal```
````

Comment: did you `console.log(formData)`? is it empty?

Comment: Yes, formData is empty

Comment: check if data.movieId is not empty, also try changing formData initialisation from const to let.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong there, i saw you have something specific for the handle submit, so you need to cast your call differently. Because when you do directly onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} you are calling directly this method on every render/update

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} id="addMovieForm"
```

```
<form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(onSubmit)} id="addMovieForm">
// if you wish to cast the event aswell
<form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e,onSubmit)} id="addMovieForm">
```

Answer (score 0):

I use react hook form (https://react-hook-form.com/get-started), and the doc say that :

````
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  console.log(watch("example")); // watch input value by passing the name of it

  return (
    /* "handleSubmit" will validate your inputs before invoking "onSubmit" */
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>```

So I don't know what I have to do xD
````

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}` to `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` as the former is supported in HTML but not in React.

   ```
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="addMovieForm">
   ```
2. Add a **name** attribute to the input field so that the key value pair for this particular input field can be stored inside `FormData`. This eliminates the `formData.append` step inside `handleSubmit()`.

   ```
   <input type="text" id="movieId" name="movieId" required></input>
   ```
3. You need to specify `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` inside  the **header** of the `POST` request.

   ```
   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();

       // Passing form element (e.target) populates the FormData object with the names and values of the fields inside it.
       const formData = new FormData(e.target);

       // formData.append("movieId", data.movieId);

       // To check formData because simply console.log(formData) won't work
       for (let item of formData) {
           console.log(item);
       }

       axios
           .post("http://localhost:5000/addMovie", formData, {
               headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
           })
           .then((response) => {
               console.log("Status: ", response.status);
               console.log("Data: ", response.data);
           })
           .catch((error) => {
               console.error("Something went wrong!", error);
           });
   };
   ```